# Slow query performance on large table with no unique keys

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb

I have a table that has approximately 20 million records and I'm having a very hard time improving the performance of the following query. It's taking well over a minute to run.

```
SELECT  a.batch_date, a.batch_number, sum(a.gross_amt) AS gross_amount,
        (sum(a.trans_fee)*-1) as trans_fee, sum(a.net_amt) AS net_amount
    FROM  cc_detail a
    WHERE  a.company_id='1'
      AND  a.account_number='999999'
      AND  (a.batch_date BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2016-01-31')
    GROUP BY  a.batch_date, a.batch_number
    ORDER BY  a.batch_date DESC, a.batch_number
    LIMIT  0, 10
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `cc_detail` ( 
    `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `account_number` int(12) NOT NULL, 
    `location_number` int(12) NOT NULL, 
    `batch_date` date NOT NULL, 
    `batch_number` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    `gross_amt` decimal(15,6) NOT NULL, 
    `trans_fee` decimal(15,6) NOT NULL, 
    `net_amt` decimal(15,6) NOT NULL, 
    KEY `company_id` (`company_id`), 
    KEY `account_number` (`account_number`),
    KEY `location_number` (`location_number`),  
    KEY `batch_date` (`batch_date`),
    KEY `batch_number` (`batch_number`), 
    KEY `ca` (`company_id`,`account_number`), 
    KEY `cab` (`company_id`,`account_number`,`batch_date`), 
    KEY `cb` (`company_id`,`batch_date`) USING BTREE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The server has 3.5 GB RAM and is running MariaDB 10.1. One issue with this table is that it does not have a primary or unique key. Due to the source of this data not having a unique key, I can not create one (unless someone has suggestions on ho to do this safely). This table is updated multiple times a day by deleting records within a date range and inserting data within that same date range.

Here is the result of the Explain statement using the above query:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: a
type: ref
possible_keys: company_id,account_number,batch_date,ca,cab,cb
key: ca
key_len: 8
ref: const, const
rows: 1
Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: You may be over indexed considering a lot of deletes and inserts.  Are the indexes fragmented?

Comment: Could you paste the result of `ANALYZE`ing your query?

Comment: Frisbee, how can I check the fragmentation of my indexes? Thanks.

Comment: Juan, I edited the question and included the result of the EXPLAIN for that query. Is that what you mean by the ANALYZE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX(a)` is unnecessary when you also have `INDEX(a,b)`. So get rid of these:

```
KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
KEY `ca` (`company_id`,`account_number`),
```

`ca` is a good index, but `cab` is better; removing `ca` will encourage the optimizer to use `cab`.  How many rows are in the result set?

Was the `SELECT` slow *during* one of those big `DELETE` + `INSERT` times?  If so, please provide those queries for further discussion.

Comment: The select query above is the most common, but can vary. In some scenarios, no batch date may be given. Would it still be wise to delete index "ca"?  I will check my logs to be sure the select and deletes do not run concurrently. I'm sure it does happen, but not often is my assumption. The delete query runs in a loop for each date within a 30 day range. DELETE FROM cc_detail where company_id=:company_id AND batch_date=:batch_date

Comment: `cap` handles any needs for `ca`, so `ca` can be deleted without loss of functionality.

Comment: I deleted all keys with the exception of cab, batch_number and location_number. Now I cannot get MySQL to use the cab index with that same query. Test using Explain and running the query takes well over 5 minutes now. Is it possible that the GROUP BY clause of the query is preventing this from using the cab index?

Comment: I suggest writing a bug report against MariaDB - https://mariadb.atlassian.net/issues/?filter=-4&jql=text%20~%20%22index%22%20order%20by%20created%20DESC

Comment: If 10.1 has `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`, apply that to the `SELECT` and show us the result.

Comment: Rick, I added a new index on batch_date to temporarily improve performance. Here is the explain json: { "query_block": { "select_id": 1, "filesort": { "temporary_table": { "function": "buffer", "table": { "table_name": "a", "access_type": "range", "possible_keys": ["cab", "batch_date"], "key": "batch_date", "key_length": "3", "used_key_parts": ["batch_date"], "rows": 148, "filtered": 100, "index_condition": "((a.batch_date >= '2010-01-01') and (a.batch_date between '2015-10-22' and '2016-01-25'))", "attached_condition": "((a.company_id = '1') and (a.account_number = '4710021'))" } } } } }

Comment: The JSON disagrees with the original `SELECT`.  Please update the question with (1) the correct `SELECT`, (2) the revised `CREATE TABLE`, and (3) add the corresponding `JSON`.

Comment: I've finally figured it out. I just needed to add the Group By columns to the end of my index. So my new index is now: company_id, account_number, batch_date, batch_number (cadb). Thanks for all your help. I'm marking your answer as correct as it is very informative and led me in the right direction.

Comment: Another tip:  Since the optimizer cannot _directly_ handle mixed directions like `ORDER BY x DESC, y ASC`, consider changing yours to `ORDER BY a.batch_date DESC, a.batch_number DESC`.  That way the `ORDER BY` and the `GROUP BY` can be done together, saving a 'sort'.